# Heap buffer overflow on a getline() - C

Tags: c, buffer, heap-memory, overflow, getline

I am coding a local server, I need to parse a file to get the config of the server.
Problem : I have a heap buffer overflow indicated at on the while.

This probeme is shown when I run with -fsanitize but I don't have any trouble without.

Here is the code :

```
struct container *configParse(FILE *file)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t n;
    char *token = NULL;
    char *saveptr = NULL;
    struct container *head = NULL;
    struct container *container = NULL;
    int key = 0;
    int first = 1;
    while ((getline(&line, &n, file)) != -1)
    {
        token = strtok_r(saveptr, " =\n\r", &line);
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (token[0] == '[')
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    container = container_init();
                    container->title = token;
                    head = container;
                    first = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    container = container_add_back(container);
                    container = container->next;
                    container->item = NULL;
                    container->title = token;
                }
                key = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (key == 0)
                {
                    if (container->item == NULL)
                    {
                        container->item = items_init();
                        container->item->key = token;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        struct item *itemcpy = container->item;
                        while (itemcpy->next != NULL)
                        {
                            itemcpy = itemcpy->next;
                        }
                        itemcpy->next = items_init();
                        itemcpy->next->key = token;
                    }
                    key = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    struct item *itemcpy = container->item;
                    while (itemcpy->next != NULL)
                    {
                        itemcpy = itemcpy->next;
                    }
                    itemcpy->value = token;
                    key = 0;
                }
            }
            token = strtok_r(NULL, " =\n\r", &line);
        }
    }
    container_print(head);
    printf("\n*****Parsing du .conf*****\n\n");
    if (isvalid(head))
        printf("Parsing OK\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Parsing KO\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

As explained I try to run the program without -fsanitze, and everything was fine

Comment: "but I don't have any trouble without." You almost certainly do, it just doesn't tell you about it.

Comment: You need to make copies of the tokens when you add them to the containers. Otherwise, all your tokens are pointers into the same `line` buffer, which gets reused each time you call `getline()`.

Comment: @Barmar That too. And using `line` for both `getline()` and as the `saveptr()` for `strtok_r()` is also likely to screw things up royally and would explain the buffer overflow in `getline()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think he just got `saveptr` and `line` confused when calling `strtok_r()`, and meant `strtok_r(line, "...", &saveptr);`

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you so much, I needed a copy of the line. It's fixed now